# Correct typing for list of ints

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Consider the following code in file x.py

```
from typing import List, Optional

my_list: List[Optional[int]] = list()
for i in range(7):
    my_list.append(i)
my_list = sorted(my_list)
if (len(my_list) > 0):
    my_list.append(None)
# do something with my_list
```

The command `mypy x.py` gives the following error:

```
x.py:6: error: Value of type variable "SupportsRichComparisonT" of "sorted" cannot be "Optional[int]"
```

So I changed x.py to the following:

```
from typing import List

my_list: List[int] = list()
for i in range(7):
    my_list.append(i)
my_list = sorted(my_list)
if (len(my_list) > 0):
    my_list.append(None)
# do something with my_list
```

But now `mypy x.py` outputs

```
x.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "None"; expected "int"
```

So how do I annotate the code correctly for mypy to not complain (of course both versions behave exactly the same during runtime and work as expected)?

The "None"-element at the end of the list is needed in the "do something"-part of the script (which is not relevant for the problem and therefore not shown here)

EDIT (19/09/2022) START
As requested, this is the productive code:

```
from typing import List, Optional

def parse_job_attributes(string: str, tokens: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    indices = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token in string.lower():
            indices.append(string.lower().index(token))
    sorted_indices: List[Optional[int]] = list(sorted(indices))

    # indices = sorted(indices)
    if len(sorted_indices) > 0:
        sorted_indices.append(None)
    parts = [string[sorted_indices[i]:sorted_indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(sorted_indices) - 1)]
    return parts
```

EDIT END

Comment: is there a reason you can not just remove `int` from `my_list: List[int]`?

Comment: Hmm... `len(my_list) > 0` will always be true since `my_list == list(range(7))`, and that also means it's already sorted. So why does the code have these pointless bits? You could turn the whole thing into `my_list: List[Optional[int]] = [*range(7), None]`. Is it just a bad example? You might want to provide a more realistic one. But FWIW, you can simplify `for x in iterable: L.append(x)` into `L.extend(iterable)`.

Comment: @crunker99: Well, in our project mypy is configured to complain about missing type parameters, so LIst[] needs to specify a type

Comment: @wjandrea: Well, the example does not show the real use-case, so in the example `len(my_list) > 0` is always true, but in the real code it is not... I know if the code were static I could write it the way you provided, but not in the productive code

Comment: @user2606240 Right, what I'm saying is, show us something closer to your real code so we can get a better feel for what you're actually doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the problem by looking at what your actual code is doing: `None` as the endpoint of the slice means `len(string)`, so if you put that instead, then your list can stay `List[int]`.

```
from typing import List

def parse_job_attributes(string: str, tokens: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    indices = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token in string.lower():
            indices.append(string.lower().index(token))
    indices.sort()

    if len(indices) > 0:
        indices.append(len(string))
    parts = [string[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
    return parts
```

This passes `mypy --strict`.

Example output, just to be sure:

```
>>> parse_job_attributes('re_foobar', ['foo', 're'])
['re_', 'foobar']
```

---

As well, since you're subtracting one from the len in `range(len(indices) - 1)`, there's not even any need to check `if len(sorted_indices) > 0`; you can append unconditionally, and the range will still be empty. That opens up some other solutions, like:

```
sorted_indices: List[Optional[int]] = [*sorted(indices), None]
```

---

P.S. Note that this whole answer is based on the "do something" part, which you thought was unimportant. I don't bring it up to shame you or anything, but to emphasize that it's important to provide working code to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The reason I initially didn't include the "do something" part was that it's not my code, just one that I should annotate afterwards... Therefore I initially "only" looked for a solution to the annotation part. But I do understand your point and already adapted the code like you proposed - and what can I say, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the sorted list back to the original variable `my_list`, assign it to a new variable which mypy will allow to hold different types.

```py
my_list: List[int] = list()
for i in range(7):
    my_list.append(i)
# change here
sorted_list: List[Any] = sorted(my_list)
if len(sorted_list) > 0:
    sorted_list.append(None)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but that gives me another error (see my answer). But it sure pointed me in the right direction. Also using Any for the new list is not allowed (project rules again), so I had to come up with something different (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73741331/2606240) )

Answer (score 1):

Based on [crunker99's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734428/2606240) that correctly pointed out the new list I was able to come up with this code that satisfies mypy:

```
from typing import List, Optional

my_list: List[int] = list()
for i in range(7):
    my_list.append(i)
my_sorted_list: List[Optional[int]] = list(sorted(my_list))
if (len(my_sorted_list) > 0):
    my_sorted_list.append(None)
# do something with my_sorted_list
```

Comment: Beside the point, but `list(sorted())` is redundant

Comment: @wjandrea Have you tried? Because for mypy (mypy 0.950, Windows 10) then complains `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[int]", variable has type "List[Optional[int]]")`

Comment: Huh, why is that significant? I tried `reveal_type(list(sorted(my_list)))` and `reveal_type(sorted(my_list))`, but they both say `builtins.list[builtins.int*]`.